# @media print for IE, bad format of my file

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I use @media print for printing web page content. User on my page can fill the fields, save it and print (download as pdf). Unfortunately, on IE and firefox can't get what is going on.

I print it to file, saving as .pdf and when I want to open this file, adobe reader scream that it's bad format of my file. I really don't know how to fix it. My code to print is just `window.print();`

Comment: Can you show us some CSS or HTML code as to what you are printing?

Comment: Yes, whole content i want to print is based on this:

`<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label" for="pracownik"> Employee</label>
   <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
    <select id="employee" class="form-control" ng-model="choose.selectedUserId" ng-options="item.userId as item.name for item in listEmployee">
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>`

Comment: So its page with form-groups and inputs for user. Generally some content is generated by JS and some user can change. It's just boostrap inputs, nothing more

Comment: Sry for this spam lol, but it's my PDF file downloaded by chrome (part of it, but whole two pages are just the same content)   https://ibb.co/grS2nF